# Force a child class to pass itself as the Generic parameter to the base class

Tags: c#, generics

I want to force my child classes to pass themselves as as the generic parameter to the parent class.

For example :

```
class BaseClass<T> where T: BaseClass
{
    //FullClassName : Tuple [Save,Update,Delete]
    Dictionary<string,Tuple<delegate,delegate,delegate>> dict = new Dictionary...;
    static BaseClass()
    {
        RegisterType();
    }

    private static void RegisterType()
    {
        Type t  = typeof(T);
        var props = t.GetProperties().Where(/* Read all properties with the SomeCustomAttribute */);
        /* Create the delegates using expression trees and add the final tuple to the dictionary */
    }

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        delegate d = dict[t.GetType().FullName];
        d.Item1(this);
    }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass<ChildClass>
{
    [SomeCustomAttribute]
    public int SomeID {get;set;}

    [SomeCustomAttribute]
    public string SomeName {get; set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
        c.Save();
    }
}
```

Obviously the above code won't compile. I'll restate : I want the child class to pass itself as the generic parameter and not any other child of BaseClass.

(The above code is kind of a psuedo code and will still not compile).

Comment: afaik: You can't force that. But you don't have to. You can simply call `GetType` to get runtime type of the instance.

Comment: If anyone is able to get an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish, could they provide an alternative. The main problem is automatically executing a one time static method for every child class. I think the static constructor will execute only once for the base and not once for every child.

Comment: Is see now... Consider instead if simply reflecting over all types and registering derived classes would work.

Comment: I think one potential problem could be that types exist across multiple assemblies and I'm not sure how and when each assembly is loaded. My code should be executed just once so that there's no unnecessary processing.

Comment: Knowing when assembly loaded is trivial - just listen for [AssemblyLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload(v=vs.110).aspx) event. It will have the same timing as static constructor you trying to invent.

Comment: Personally I'd just add runtime check that type is correct and be done with it as I tried to suggest in my answer... But it does not really solve your problem nicely.

Comment: What does `RegisterType` do? I agree with the others that this is pretty smelly code. It also sounds like you are trying to implement AOP without AOP.

Comment: A static constructor is only called just before the first instance of an object is instantiated, not when an application starts or when an assembly is loaded. Sounds like your missing a service to register types. Do thinks explicitly.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov why do you want to implement Runtime checks on your code? Isn't it a bit late by then? Shouldn't it be a compile time check, or even better a design time check.

Comment: RegisterType will create a runtime delegate using ExpressionTrees. This delegate will read/write from xml/class properties. It's like creating my own NHibernate or EntityFramework, having said that I cannot use those two ORM's since our database is not that simple. It's columns, stored procs and auditing procs are generated from a tool which reads the configuration from an xml file which is generated on a different system.

Comment: @Aron - because compile time check OP is looking for is not possible. So failing at runtime (i.e. as soon as one write first unit test for new class) with something like "you must pass your class to generic base" is next reasonable option (assuming given behavior is must and some other registration is not acceptable).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what do you mean its not possible? If its possible in reflection its possible to run it as a part of the compilation toolchain as a post compilation step using an AOP framework. There is also the possibility of using `UnitTest` which is what I would have done before I discovered AOP/MSIL Weaving.

Comment: @Aron I'm just cant express anything today... will delete the comments.. I was trying to say something like "using regular C# and regular C# compiler one can't express compile time check that forces derived class... "

Comment: @ChrisSerrao Either use UnitTests or use AOP add the behavior you need for your class. A static constructor is the wrong place to check for the correctness of your code.

Comment: Its clear this is an XY problem.

Comment: @Aron: It looks like OP is trying to implement Dependency Injection, but has merged types into a single class hierarchy that should be distinct.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens : AFAIK, dependency injection is used to create instances of objects at runtime where the type of object can be centrally configure. My problem on the other hand is that the developers must repeat code such as xdoc.SelectSingleNode(someXPathExpression).Value = myobject.Property and then pass that to another object XmlToDatabaseSaver.Save(xdoc), foreach and every property and perform vice-versa. This should be done automatically without the need to repeate the code for every class, which will be managed from the base class.

Comment: I fail to see this as a solution that can be solved using dependency injection.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
public class BaseClass<T> where T: BaseClass<T> { }

public class ChildClass : BaseClass<ChildClass> { }
```

But this doesn't **force** you to use `ChildClass` as the generic parameter. You could do this `public class OtherChildClass : BaseClass<ChildClass> { }` which would break the "coontract" that you want to enforce.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer is that if your accessing a static method then typeof(T) will give you the type for reflection.

However, there is probably better solutions than using reflection. Options:

1) Static constructor on the child class.

2) Abstract method declared in the base class.

I do not know the application, but I get concerned about my design if I feel like using a static constructor, I also get concerned if a base class needs to initialize the child class.

I suggest looking at injection as a solution rather than inheritance. It offers superior unit testing and often a better architecture.

More info (after initial post), this is my preferred solution:

```
public interface IRegesterable
{
    void Register();
}

public class Widget : IRegesterable
{
    public void Register()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public Class1(IRegesterable widget)
    {
        widget.Register();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I am not going to create instances of the child using reflection. We have a framework that needs some redundant code to be implemented and needs a learning curve per developer.The code cannot be moved to a base class since it involves reading and writing to xml. I want them to create Data model classes and mark their properties using attributes and I'll use reflections and expression trees to create delegates that'll do all that redundant work for them without them even knowing what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: The problem with the updated solution is that the reflection code or even simply the code to check if reflection has been performed would need to be executed per object created.Also, I don't want the developers doing anything, I might even write code to generate the classes and have them just test it. I want to eliminate human errors.

Comment: See my updated response. Interface and injection? I often find inheritance makes my code less maintainable and certainly less testable.

Comment: I do not propose reflection. Use interfaces and injection instead. Compile time validation and avoids obfuscation (more readable code).

Comment: Rob, the reflection code will execute just once per class, for the lifetime of the object. Delegates will be generated using ExpressionTress, which means less processing, runtime method generation. Please read my first comment. I will not be creating instances of the class, I will create some secret code that will perform redundant tasks that the developers would write for saving, deleting, etc. They are responsible for creating the class objects and they will decide which objects they want to create and when they want to create them.

Comment: If you want to execute just once you can use a static constructor. But, I do think that using reflection usually/often leads to complication through unnecessary obfuscation. I hoping to help by solving a code problem and giving opinion on good coding rather than solving a explicit application (which I cannot know in full).

Comment: Yes, Rob, I'll have to check that I guess. I thought that the static constructor would execute just once for the class in which it is declared and not once for every child class. That's the reason in bringing in generic type parameters.

Comment: Just once for the class - yes. But only just before the first instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

The `ConcurrentDictionary` is being used as a `Set<Type>`. We can check in the `Set<Type>` if the type has been initialized. If not we run `RegisterType` on the type.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    //Concurrent Set does not exist.
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, bool> _registeredTypes 
            = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, bool>();

    protected BaseClass()
    {
        _registeredTypes.GetOrAdd(GetType(), RegisterType);
    }

    private static bool RegisterType(Type type)
    {
        //some code that will perform one time processing using reflections

        //dummy return value
        return true;
    }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
}
```

There are several inefficiencies with this pattern though.

- `object.GetType()` is pretty darn slow, and inefficient.
- Even with the `HashSet` behavior, we are checking for initialization on each instanciation. Its as fast as I can get it, but its still pretty superfluous.